# How to debug decompiled code by jd-intelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, decompiling

I am using IntelliJ Idea 12 and 13. We don't have sources so we need to decompile byte code to understand the logic.

I have installed jd-intelliJ plugin, it seems it works fine, but I don't have an ability to put a breakpoint in decompiled code.

I've tried to use JAD plugin before, but the decompiled code is so ugly when I use this plugin. Also I've tried to decompile jar file by jd-GUI, put it into my maven repository and used it to debug in IntelliJ, it also doesn't work correctly.

Is there any way to use good decompiler like JD and debug it in my Idea IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latest version of JD-GUI have an ability to realign line numbers. (Help->Preferences)

When the line numbers is aligned correctly there shouldn't be a problem with debugging the source that is attached in your maven project.

Comment: There are huge problems with stepping in any decompiled class. Try to debug Tibco library with it. It is just not working neither with line alignment nor without

Comment: I have tried to realign the line numbers by JD-GUI, but when the decompiled class has a lot of line numbers, unfortunately the numbers don't match and debugger point isn't placed correctly :( So this decision is good only when the classes aren't very long.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is to use a decompiler to extract java files from the class files. Once you have the java files, it should be easier to use Intellij/Eclipse with the java files when debugging. What you are using is the Intellij Decompiler Plugin that shows you the java code but doesn't let you extract it in to java files: that you should do with the JD-GUI, which has a Save command.